# Makefile works in bash but fails in zsh. Can you point out error in syntax of for loop?

Tags: makefile, zsh

Here's the beginning of a GNUMakefile that works well under bash but has failed since I switched to zsh (and oh-my-zsh). It is annoying that I need to start a bash shell to perform it, so do you think you can help point out the syntax problem?

```
SUBDIRS = generator geometry io management physicslist processing


makeall:
        @echo "********************************************************************************"
        @echo " Building Project"
        @echo "********************************************************************************"
        @for dir in $(SUBDIRS); do (echo; echo; echo Building $$dir...; cd $$dir; $(MAKE) "SUBDIRS=$(SUBDIRS)"); done
```

This results in an infinite loop:

```
[●]% make
********************************************************************************
 Building Project
********************************************************************************


Building generator...
/bin/sh: line 0: cd: generator: No such file or directory
********************************************************************************
 Building Project
********************************************************************************


Building generator...
/bin/sh: line 0: cd: generator: No such file or directory
********************************************************************************
 Building Project
********************************************************************************
...
...
```

It seems I fork-bomb myself with make's and /bin/sh's:

```
...
...
24921 ttys012    0:00.00 make SUBDIRS=generator geometry io management physicslist processing
24925 ttys012    0:00.00 /bin/sh -c for dir in generator geometry io management physicslist processing; do (echo; echo; echo Building $dir...; cd $dir; make "SUBDIRS=generator geometry io man
24926 ttys012    0:00.00 /bin/sh -c for dir in generator geometry io management physicslist processing; do (echo; echo; echo Building $dir...; cd $dir; make "SUBDIRS=generator geometry io man
24927 ttys012    0:00.00 make SUBDIRS=generator geometry io management physicslist processing
24931 ttys012    0:00.00 /bin/sh -c for dir in generator geometry io management physicslist processing; do (echo; echo; echo Building $dir...; cd $dir; make "SUBDIRS=generator geometry io man
24932 ttys012    0:00.00 /bin/sh -c for dir in generator geometry io management physicslist processing; do (echo; echo
...
...
```

EDIT:

The makefile inside of generator looks like:

```
name := generator

include ../ProgramConfig/Libraries.gmk
```

Libraries.gmk looks like

```
.PHONY: all lib
all: lib

include ../ProgramConfig/BuildDirs.gmk

include $(G4INSTALL)/config/architecture.gmk
include $(G4INSTALL)/config/common.gmk

include ../ProgramConfig/ExtraDeps.gmk
include ../ProgramConfig/GEANT4.gmk

# Add the sub-directory include directories to the compilation list
CPPFLAGS += $(addprefix -I../, $(addsuffix /include, $(SUBDIRS))) -O2

cleanup:
    cd $(G4WORKDIR)
    rm -rf bin tmp lib
```

Comment: The syntax looks correct, and it will go into an infinite loop if one of the subdirs is missing. Are you sure that there is a `generator` subdirectory? Try `makeall: @ls | grep generator` to be sure. Also, there are safer ways to get it to iterate over the subdirs.

Comment: @Beta: The subdirectories are all there and the makefile works fine with bash. To explore the option, though, what would be a safer way to iterate over the subdirs?

Answer (score 2):

Experiment 1. Try this:

```
makeall:
    @for dir in $(SUBDIRS); do (echo Building $$dir...; cd $$dir; $(MAKE) "SUBDIRS=$(SUBDIRS)" ; cd -); done
```

And the safer method I had in mind: iterate in Make, not in the shell.

```
makeall: $(SUBDIRS)

.PHONY: $(SUBDIRS)

$(SUBDIRS):
    @echo Building $@
    @cd $@; $(MAKE) "SUBDIRS=$(SUBDIRS)"
```

Note that you can also make that last rule a little cleaner:

```
$(SUBDIRS):
    @echo Building $@
    @$(MAKE) -C $@ "SUBDIRS=$(SUBDIRS)"
```

Comment: Still an infinite loop with the same output, but since the loop is in Make I can ^C out and avoid the fork bomb. At least I'll be able to diagnose it further a bit easier.

Comment: @vgm64: Wait a second. Could you show us the makefile that's in `generator/`?